# Empty field in admin to do something?

Tags: custom-options

i have a custom option in my module such as name `stockmessages_min_qty`. I want to if the field has no data `(empty field label text)` my codes make something. I try in my `block.php` file:

```
if(Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_min_qty') == empty) { 
    echo str_replace('%s', intval($quantity) ,$cartmess);
    }
```

The line with `== empty`, or `== null`,or `== 0`, do nothing in my frontend . What i have to do for use the **option** with Empty value ?

Comment: `var_dump(Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_min_qty'))` to see it's value and proceed from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with comparing with an empty string?

```
if(Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_min_qty') == '') {
```